# Create 3 vertical split layout using html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a home page for my web application. I'm thinking of 3 vertical split layout for it. I have some piece of code to create 3 horizontal splits but however, my goal is to create 3 vertical splits. How can I do that?

The image below is to create 3 horizontal splits but again my objective is to create 3 vertical splits.
[image]

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; height :100%;  background-color:Lime;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:34%; background-color:Blue;">
      a
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:33%; background-color:Gray;">
      b
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:33%; background-color:Aqua;">
      c
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The expected output is 3 vertical split layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow _

To neaten the code put the `flex` & `height` elements into CSS classes

```
// parent div
.flexDisplay { 
     flex: 1;
     height: 100%;
}

// child divs
.flexHeight {
     display: flex;
     height: 100%;
}

.flexHeightResize {
     display: flex;
     height: 50%; // adjust percentage as required
}
```

then add to HTML

```
<div class="flexDisplay" style="background-color:Lime;">
    <div class="flexHeight" style="background-color:Blue;">
    A
    </div>
    <div class="flexHeightResize" style="background-color:Gray;">
    B
    </div>
    <div class="flexHeight" style="background-color:Aqua;">
    C
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flexDisplay {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.flexHeight { 
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.flexHeightResize { 
    flex: 1;
    height: 50%; // adjust percentage as required
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flexDisplay" style="background-color:Lime;">
        <div class="flexHeight" style="background-color:Blue;">
        A
        </div>
        <div class="flexHeightResize" style="background-color:Gray;">
        B
        </div>
        <div class="flexHeight" style="background-color:Aqua;">
        C
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Such a good way of dividing the layout, but one more thing how can I resize the middle split?

Comment: I assumed you meant "_resize the middle split_ " horizontally _ I have rewritten the snippet to show you how _ Adjust the CSS `height` percentage in `.flexHeightResize` to suit your needs

Comment: I mean resizing the width of the middle split. How?

Comment: Everything you need to learn about how to use Flex is here >>> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ _ and here's another link which is specific to controlling the width of flex columns >>> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax

Comment: This is a cheat sheet for Flexbox which includes `flex-grow` & `flex-shrink` which are what you're looking for >>> https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/ _ Sorry I can't be more help right now_ I'm tied down to another task _ Thanks for marking my answer _ appreciated _ Good Luck ; )

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One is to use `inline-block` level display to line your divs up. The height here is arbitrary. Consider the following:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33.33%;
  margin-right:-4px;
  height:500px;
}
.column-a {background-color:Blue;}
.column-b {background-color:Gray;}
.column-c {background-color:Aqua;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column column-a">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="column column-b">
      b
    </div>
    <div class="column column-c">
      c
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Another way to do this would be to use `flex` display. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spjny19o/) with a simple example. You can use the same markup, but change your css to this:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
}
.column {
  flex:1;
  height:100vh;
}
.column-a {background-color:Blue;}
.column-b {background-color:Gray;}
.column-c {background-color:Aqua;}
```

Comment: Thank you. Another thing, how can I change the size of the middle split? What I'm trying to do next is to make column a and c as fixed side bar with equal size. And resize column be to much become wider than the sidebar

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spjny19o/1/). Is this what you mean? If so you can just change the width of each column appropriately. As long as they equal 100% total.

Comment: when I try your code the splits height was not fitted to my screen.

Comment: @King you can use `100vh` as the `height` property for full height. As I said in my answer, the `height` property in the example is arbitrary.

Comment: Okay wait doing now.

Comment: its already okay now. Thanks you solved the problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: flex` on the parent and `flex: 1; height: 100%` on the children

Comment: flex is used for?

Comment: Flex is used for easier and responsive layout in css. Check it out at  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/